# MYSQL group by month,year and get highest score for month

Tags: mysql

Please could someone help me?

I am trying to get the last 10 winners for a photo of the month competition with most recent first excluding the current month, here is what I have so far:-

```
SELECT
            *,
            MAX(total_score)
        FROM
            comp_images
        WHERE
            date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),Interval 10 Month) AND curdate()
        AND
            CONCAT(MONTH(curdate()),'',YEAR(curdate())) != CONCAT(MONTH(date_added),'',YEAR(date_added))
        AND
            url != ''
        AND
            hide = '0'
        GROUP BY
            MONTH(date_added)
        ORDER BY
            total_score DESC
        LIMIT 10
```

Any help with would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are getting all images back, with the max total score. The problem here is you are separately selecting all rows (with *) and the MAX(total_score) but have not bound them together.

What you could do to solve this is using the HAVING keyword of MySQL. You can give criteria to your select all rows statement. So for example:

```
SELECT * FROM comp_images..... HAVING MAX(total_score);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Kevin but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has the same issue here is the solution I found:

```
SELECT
            * , CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date_added),' ',YEAR(date_added)) as win_month
        FROM (select * from comp_images order by total_score desc) x
        WHERE
            date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(),Interval 10 Month) AND curdate()
        AND
            CONCAT(MONTH(curdate()),'',YEAR(curdate())) != CONCAT(MONTH(date_added),'',YEAR(date_added))
        AND
            url != ''
        AND
            hide = '0'
        GROUP BY
            MONTH(date_added)
        LIMIT 10
```